# Building boost 1.66 lib for ARM using b2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have cloned the repo for boost 1.66 and I'm trying to build for arm using the following command: 
b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 architecture=arm. However, this does not seem to work, the building process works for other architectures such as x86 but not ARM. I have an error with; "This file does not have an app associated with it for perfomring this action.. Please install an app or, if one is already isntalled, crfeate an assocationa in the Default Apps Settings page. "

Comment: I don't think the MSVC compiler cross conpiles for the ARM architecture. You need the GCC cross compiler for ARM for that.

Comment: Do you have VC tools for ARM installed and available in the environment?

Comment: @user7860670 I have VC 14.25 I have later changed to try and use 14.25 however, I am still getting this error. However, it does say during the configuration checks "arm:no(cached)" is in there, I'm not sure how to change that though.I'm quite new to all of this. I think they started supporting it with the hololens2.

Comment: So do you have VC tools for ARM installed or not?

Comment: Yes I do have it installed